Visual Studio Code Terminal Running Slow Despite Various Optimizations
Body:
Hello community,
I'm experiencing significant slowdowns with the terminal in Visual Studio Code on my Windows system, and I'm looking for further insights or solutions. Despite trying multiple optimizations, the issue persists.
System Information:

VS Code Version: 1.90.0
Operating System: Windows 10
CPU: Intel Core i7
RAM: 32 GB, with about 16 GB free

Issue Description:
The terminal in Visual Studio Code is responding very slowly. This performance issue occurs despite relatively low CPU and memory usage across the system and within the app itself. I've noticed multiple instances of VS Code running, but closing them hasn't improved the situation.
Question:
Despite these efforts, the terminal continues to perform poorly. The commands work, but every time I wait a little longer than two seconds for the result. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or does anyone have suggestions on what else I can try to resolve this? Could there be a deeper underlying issue with Visual Studio Code or Windows that I might be missing?
Thank you in advance for any help or guidance you can provide!
Steps Tried:

Disabling All Extensions: Ran VS Code with the --disable-extensions flag to rule out any extensions causing the slowdown.
Reducing Resource Usage: Closed unnecessary instances and processes to free up resources.
Adjusting Terminal Settings:
Set "terminal.integrated.gpuAcceleration": "off"
Reduced scrollback lines and disabled cursorBlinking.
System Checks:
Checked for any system file corruption with sfc /scannow.
Monitored other applications and processes for excessive resource usage.
Reinstalling Visual Studio Code: Performed a clean installation to rule out issues with the installation.

Video YOUTUBE:


Do you really suspect this terminal? Maybe it's bash itself. What happens when you use a different terminal?

It happens to me as well. Here are some suggestions https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/214407

All good when I am trying to you external terminal, only in VS code have that issue

I just found a case where Microsoft Visual Studio Code Terminal is capped to about 12,000 bauds. All you need is to print a log with lots of color escape sequences. I used tmux to compare the speed with the native terminal mintty. I can confirm it's only VS code's problem.

Basically this will give you back your life: "terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled to false" (it did to me).
Source: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/214407
A more visual fix is:

Thanks to xGeekoo, Lord-Fec and to nbrinks

I tried but it didn't work. Still the same

did you close/shut down current terminal and open a new one? this is needed, as mentioned in the reference url.

yes, check the video, there strange latency
